# php pdo постоянное соединение

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Помогите нубасу.
Есть сайт, в котором онлайн +30 человек. 
Эти 30 человек активно взаимодействуют с 3 базами данных. Одна локальная, другие - нет (права только на селект).

Есть ли смысл делать постоянное соединение на базы, которые не расположены локально?
Меня очень напрягает:

> Есть еще два дополнительных предостережения, которые следует помнить при работе с постоянными соединениями. В случае, если скрипт блокирует таблицу и по каким-либо причинам не может ее освободить, при использовании постоянного соединения все последующие скрипты, которые используют это соединение будут блокированы бесконечно долго и могут потребовать рестарта веб-сервера или сервера баз данных. Второе предостережение заключается в том, что открытые транзакции, если они не были закрыты до завершения работы скрипта, будут продолжены в следующем скрипте, использующем это же постоянное соединение. Исходя из этого, вы можете использовать функцию register_shutdown_function() для указания простой функции, которая снимает блокировку таблиц или отката ваших транзакций. Еще лучше избежать этих проблем полностью, не используя постоянные соединения в скриптах, которые используют блокировку таблиц или транзакции (при этом вы все еще можете использовать их где-то в другом месте).

```
try {
        $this->db = new PDO($config['adapter'] . ':host=' . $config['hostname'] . ';port='.$config['port'].';dbname=' . $config['dbname'],
                        $config['username'], $config['password'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    } catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как удаленно у вас исключительно SELECT, то блокировок можно не бояться.

Но если есть возможность использовать API (или написать), то есть запрашивать данные не в БД напрямую, а с помощью скрипта работающего на удаленном сервере - то лучше так.

Сервер вы не оложите - уже довольно продолжительное время mysql устойчив к разрушениям коннекта. Но насколько меделенно это все будет работать....